# socket.io is not receiving or sending events

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have a socket.io project and my client is using android. Connection event is fired on the server-side but join match is not. any ideas why?

```
socket.connect();
```

on the client-side, fires the below code on server-side:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    try {
            console.log("connected!");
            self.handleJoinMatch(io, socket);
        })
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex.toString());
    }
});
```

`connected` is logged on the console. `handleJoinMatch` function is:

```
handleJoinMatch(io, socket) {
        console.log("handle join match is called!");
        socket.on('join match', (params) => {
            console.log("join matched is recieved!");

.........
```

`handle join match is called!` is logged on the console as well, but the below code does nothing:

```
socket.emit("join match");
```

update1:
I should mention the even after 10 minutes if I close the android app, the below code is called:

```
socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
    console.log("disconnected");
......
```

update2: 
I just realized that in my client, after `socket.connect()`, `socket.connected()` returns false and `socket.on("connect", connectHandler);` is not being called at all.

Comment: Where do you put your `socket.emit("join match");` in the code?

Comment: @TamasSzoke It is in `onCreate` method and I am sure it is called (I have put a log before it). The problem is even events that I emit them from server are not received in the client as well

Comment: You should try it with params and simple namespace: `socket.emit("test", "123");`

Comment: @TamasSzoke That's not working either

Comment: @TamasSzoke would you please check my question updates?